# microsoft word find and replace

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

From a word file , I want to replace alternate occurence of a character.By using Find & Replace all the occurences will be replaced.Is there any way to replace only alternate occurences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Microsoft Word, you can create a macro to do just that. You basically start recording and do those steps (assuming you copied the new character in the clipboard):

```
Press F3 to find next.
Ctrl-V to paste over.
Press F3 to ignore the next.
```

Stop recording and execute the macro until the end of the file is reached.

MS Word 2010 - http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-make-a-macro-in-word-2010.html